# require Statement returns Transaction Revert Error instead of provided custom error message

Tags: node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

For example, i have this piece of code here `require(keys[_address].purpose != _purpose, "Key Already Exists");` in a Smart Contract. Upon executing a function and failing a requirement, require statement does not return the defined error message. Instead it returns **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM**. I am writing an application in Node JS and i know my code works correctly because i tested it with different type of inputs and it provide the correct outputs.

I am using Truffle for development with parity. I tested it with Remix and it provides me defined error message so issue is not with the code

My actual question is why require statement does not return the provided error message?. Am i missing something?. Do i need to provide a certain flag to **parity** or setup something to catch the provided error message?. Any suggestion would be helpful

**Smart Contract Code:**

```
address public administrator;

constructor() public
    {
        administrator = msg.sender;
        addKey(msg.sender, 1, 1);
        emit KeyAdded(msg.sender, 1, 1);
    }
   
mapping(address => Key)keys;
mapping(uint256 => address[])keysByType;
mapping(uint256 => address[])keysByPurpose;

event KeyAdded(address indexed key, uint256 indexed purpose, uint256 indexed keyType);

struct Key {
        uint256 purpose;
        uint256 keyType;
        address key;
    }

modifier onlyAdmin
    {
        require(msg.sender == administrator, "Sender is not admin");
        _;
    }

function addKey(address _address, uint256 _purpose, uint256 _type) public onlyAdmin override returns(bool success)
    {
        require(keys[_address].purpose != _purpose, "Key Already Exists");
        keys[_address].key = _address;
        keys[_address].purpose = _purpose;
        keys[_address].keyType = _type;

        keysByType[_type].push(_address);
        keysByPurpose[_purpose].push(_address);

        emit KeyAdded(_address, _purpose, _type);
        return true;
    }
```

**Node JS Sample Execution:**

```
myContract.methods.addKey("00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72", 3, 1).send({from:"00a329c0648769a73afac7f9381e08fb43dbea72", gas:4613288}).then(console.log)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solidity `require()` statement

- Does not return an error message
- Aborts the Ethereum transaction - there is no return value
- Ethereum transaction writes the error message in special area of transaction data

[Here is the specification for this behavior: EIP-140](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-140).

What you are observing is the lack of Truffle's ability to extract this error message from the transaction. I do not know how it works with Truffle, but for example, [OpenZeppelin SDK](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-sdk/blob/master/packages/lib/src/test/helpers/assertRevert.ts), an alternative for Truffle, can do it. I suggest asking in Truffle discussion forums or asking a Truffle specific question if you want to solve this problem for Truffle.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But the problem was not with Truffle as i was only using it to compile my contracts and get ABI. I researched and still i am not 100% certain but it is believed to have been a problem with parity client. And if you try the same code in Remix IDE. it provides you the error message in return.

Comment: https://soliditydeveloper.com/web3-1-2-5-revert-reason-strings